# If $q$ is a monic polynomial, then $qf=qg \implies f=g$

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

> For a monic polynomial $q\in R[X]$, prove that $qf=qg$ implies $f=g$,
>   where $f,g\in R[X]$.

Note: by assumption, rings are commutative.

I don't understand this problem. Can't I just say "perform polynomial division by $q$ on both sides"? Does it not work this way?

Also, if I could show that $R[X]$ is a field, then I could multiply on the left by $q^{-1}$. But $R[X]$ is not necessarily a field. Is there something about $q$ being monic that implies it has a multiplicative inverse?

Thanks!

Comment: Is $R$ an arbitrary ring or are there assumptions on $R$?

Comment: $R[X]$ is not a field. You can't, in general, divide by a $q$ if $q$ is not monic, so you'll need that $q$ is monic.

Comment: Commutative ring. Sorry--let me edit the question

Comment: How does $q$ being monic allow me to divide by it?

Comment: That's what you need to prove. :)

Comment: I see! Let me try:

Comment: I see that we can't divide $aX^n$ by $bX^m$ because $a/b$ is not necessarily an integer. If $b=1$, then we definitely have at least one term $aX^{n-m}$. But what I'm worried about is the case when $\deg(q)>\deg(f)$. We might still not be able to divide them, even if $q$ is monic.

Comment: Don't think division, just show that if $q$ is monic and $qf=0$ then $f=0$.

Comment: How can I take the step after that to say that $qf=qg\implies f=g$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint:** Basically, you need to prove that $qf=0$ implies $f=0$.

This is not true if $q$ is not monic - specifically, if $q$ has a zero divisor for initial coefficient. Take $R=\mathbb Z/4\mathbb Z$, with $q=f=2X$.

Comment: I proved that a monic $q\in R[X]$ does not have a zero divisor (this was earlier in the assignment). It does not have a zero divisor because if $a=a_n X^n +\cdots \in R[X]$ then $qa=a_n  X^{k+n} +\cdots$ and $a_n\neq 0$

Comment: This means that $qf\neq 0$ for all $f\neq 0$.

Comment: Hence, $qf=0$ implies $f=0$.

Comment: That first comment is imprecise. "Does not have a zero divisor" is the wrong use of language. You've proven a monic polynomial is not a zero divisor. But yes, your argument is correct. Now, apply this to $qf=qg$, which would mean $q(f-g)=0$ which means...

Comment: Oh!! Got it! Thank you!